# splitting the sum into two sums

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Why can I split the sum $$\sum_{k\equiv0(5)}e^{2\pi i k /5}$$ into $$\sum_{k\ mod\ 10 \\k \equiv0(5)}\sum_{r\equiv k(10)}e^{2\pi ir/5}?$$
Actually I am trying to understand why the sum $\sum_{\nu\equiv0(\mathfrak{\overline a})}$ can be split into $$\sum_{\alpha\ mod (\mathfrak{\overline a}Q\sqrt{D})\\\alpha \equiv0(\mathfrak{ \overline a})}\sum_{\mu\equiv\alpha(\mathfrak{\overline a}Q\sqrt{D})} ,$$
where $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal with its conjugate ideal $\mathfrak{ \overline a}, Q \in \mathbb{N},D \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: The sum runs through residue classes $k$ mod $10$, but only if $k\equiv 0$ mod $5$... so the sum is only for $k\equiv 0,5$ mod $10$. Isn't this clearly identical to summing over multiples of $5$?

Comment: yes, I know it is quite obvious, but is there a method that allows  us to split this sum in this way? For example if we  sum over an ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to look for. Why do we even need to look at ideals in this situation?